# Why does figure 2 and 6 deform differently from the other shapes?

Tags: buckling

I am doing a linear buckling analysis on all the structures you see below, they are subjected to compression load in the x-axis as indicated by the arrow. You can see all structures beside 2 and 6 deform differently from the rest. Do you guys know why that might be?

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. If you do a buckling analysis on six completely different structures, why should any of the buckled shapes be *the same* as each other? Also, if the graphs are relevant to the question, what do the labels on the X axis mean?

Comment: Its called irreducible Bruillone zone and it is complicated, but here is an example picture: https://imgur.com/a/DGOfm44 , but just by looking at the geometry - do you see any reason why it might be buckling the way it does when they all are subjected to the same load. And here is a wikipedia entry that explains the x-axis if you have the time: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone

Comment: And didn’t all your previous questions about these structures give you the information?

Comment: Well, that explains what they are, but it doesn't explain why you think the buckling modes should be the same. FWIW I am very familiar with working with a 1-D version of this type of Fourier decomposition (called "cyclic symmetry") and I can't really imagine any use for a linear buckling analysis of one cell.  So I'll pass on trying to answer the question!

Comment: Could you please say more about performing linear buckling analysis of one cell? Its related to the work I am doing now where Bloch-Floquet boundary conditions are used to find global buckling, not only cell-periodic.

Comment: What do you want me to add to "I can't really imagine any use for a linear buckling analysis of one cell." (Years ago I remember somebody with more enthusiasm than understanding who tried to model nonlinear contact problem using Fourier analysis and then asked "what does it mean when the program says the 2nd harmonic of the displacement is in contact but the 3rd harmonic is not...")  [Apologies to those who can't see the joke here].

Comment: OK, I just found thiis paper: https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/bertoldi/files/prsa_jia.pdf. But skimming it, if this is what you are trying todo I think you have misunderstood what a linear buckling analysis actually calculates.

Comment: Think of force as something that flows - like electricity through conductors.  It prefers paths of least resistance but what goes in at one end comes out at another (otherwise the structure accelerates).  High stress and hence deformation occurs where it has less area to flow through.